# YouTube iFrame throwing QUIC Protocol Errors

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

In the last month or so we have seen a sharp increase in users seeing a QUIC Protocol Error when trying to load the iFrame (see attached error message).

When this happens the Youtube iFrame player does not work unless we re-load the page. This is happening specifically on Vizio Smartcast TVs (which use a Chrome browser but have a user agent that makes it look like a Chromecast device).

Is there a way to tell the YouTube iFrame player to not use QUIC? Or else is there another way you can suggest to resolve this issue?

[image: QUIC PROTOCOL ERROR]